# Find the values of an Object using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find the values of a JavaScript object using Regex.

Sample object: `classes: {wrapper: 'sm-mb--1-half md-mb--2', item: 'sm-mb--quarter sm-mt--quarter'}`

Expected output: `sm-mb--1-half md-mb--2 sm-mb--quarter sm-mt--quarter`

What I have so far `/\{([A-Za-z]*:\s'.*',?\s?)*\}/gm`, but for some reason it selects everything..

Sandbox:
https://regex101.com/r/hQfHKN/1

Comment: Why would you use Regex to process an Object? That's like using a screwdriver to hammer in a nail.

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned, I am working on a script that parses JS files and grabs the classnames used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lookahead` and `Lookbehind` you can achieve what you want.

```js
let str = `classes: {wrapper: 'sm-mb--1-half md-mb--2', item: 'sm-mb--quarter sm-mt--quarter'}`;

const regex = /(?<={.*:).*?(?=,|})/g;

console.log(str.match(regex))
```